# Odds ratio for ordinal variables from PROC GENMOD

Tags: sas, bioinformatics, glm, medical

I have a set of data where I am creating a logistic regression model, looking at the odds of a binary outcome variable (Therapy), with Stage as an ordinal explanatory variable (0,1,2,3,4). A1c is a continuous variable. Because each patient has two eyes, I must use the repeated subject = patientID(EyeID) statement.

The following is my code:

```
PROC GENMOD data=new descend;
      class patientID EyeID Stage (param = ordinal) Therapy (ref ="0") Gender(ref="M") Ethnic agegroup/ PARAM=ref;
      model Therapy = Stage A1c gender AGEGROUP Ethnic/ dist=bin;
      repeated subject=patientID(EyeID) / corr=unstr corrw;
      lsmeans Stage / ilink exp oddsratio diff cl;
run;
```

Because Stage is an ordinal variable, I would like to get odds ratios for Stage 4 vs 0, 3 vs 0, 2 vs 0, etc, so I put in the lsmeans statement. However, I got this error: "WARNING: The model does not have a GLM parameterization. This parameterization is required for the TEST, LSMEANS, LSMESTIMATE, and 
          SLICE statement. These statements are ignored."

Any thoughts?

I have checked the design matrix for the class variables and they are correct.

```
Class Level Information
Class   Value   Design Variables
Stage 0     0   0   0   0        
    1   1.000   0   0   0        
    2   1.000   1.000   0   0        
    3   1.000   1.000   1.000   0        
    4   1.000   1.000   1.000   1.000        
Gender  F   1.000                    
    M   0                    
Ethnic  AA  1.000   0                
    As  0   1.000                
    C   0   0
```

Comment: Not an expert on this, so I'll give you something to try as a comment.  I have no clue if it will work.  If it does, I'll make it an answer.  Try changing the `ref=` in the `CLASS` statement to `ref=GLM`.

Comment: @DomPazz The `param=ref` or the `ref=` after the Gender and Therapy variables?