# In SAS: How to produce odds ratios (OR) in the results of PROC GENMOD

Tags: sas

Possibly related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46748234/odds-ratio-for-ordinal-variables-from-proc-genmod) question: How can I print odds ratios as part of the results of a `GENMOD` procedure?

I am dealing with a wide dataset containing; a main exposure variable, a categorical variable `Type` (four levels), as several continuous and binary variables as confounding factors.

Additional info: The dataset contains multiple imputations.

I am using the following code:

```
Proc genmod;

Class ID Type (ref=first)
Model class1= Type;
estimate 'black' TYPE 0 1 1/exp;
estimate 'white' TYPE 1 0 1/exp;
estimate 'red' TYPE 0 1 0/exp;
Repeated ID;

By imputation;
Run;
```

I expected the results table to contain, among others, the beta for the exponential of every level of the categorical variable `Type` ( bar that variable's reference group). The actual results table lacks beta values, nor does the table have confidence intervals printed.

What syntax should I use to tell SAS to produce those numbers in the results? I have looked through SAS documentation, but I have yet found an answer.

Comment: [link](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=statug&docsetTarget=statug_genmod_syntax13.htm&docsetVersion=14.3&locale=en) says "You can specify the following options in the ESTIMATE statement after a slash (/)." and "E requests that the  matrix coefficients be displayed."

Comment: Also adding EXP will show the confidence limits.